# Using for loop to generate table row in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, for-loop

Please review my code below what am i doing wrong am trying to generate a list of table row using for loop.
And the result am getting return just the last item in my list and stop, but i when i use a print it shows its generating the items as it surpose to.

```
class CustomTableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTableRow({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder(
          top: containerBorderSide,
          bottom: containerBorderSide,
          horizontalInside: containerBorderSide),
      children: [
        returnRestoreWord(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

BorderSide containerBorderSide = BorderSide(
  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
  width: 2,
);

List<String> restoreWords = [
  'Abandon',
  'Ability',
  'Divorce',
  'Leopard',
  'Scale',
  'Lens',
  'Music'
];

TableRow returnRestoreWord() {
  String words = '';
  for (String word in restoreWords) {
    words = word;
  }
  return TableRow(children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Text(
        words,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      ),
    )
  ]);
}
```

Please review my code below what am i doing wrong am trying to generate a list of table row using for loop.
And the result am getting return just the last item in my list and stop, but i when i use a print it shows its generating the items as it surpose to.

Comment: change
    `words = word;`
to
    `words = words + word;`

Comment: Or do you want a TableRow for each word?

Comment: Yes I want a TableRow for each word @JohnWeidner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
class CustomTableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomTableRow({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      border: TableBorder(
          top: containerBorderSide,
          bottom: containerBorderSide,
          horizontalInside: containerBorderSide),
      children: [
        for ( final word in restoreWords )
          TableRow(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Text(
                word,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ])
        
      ],
    );
  }
}

BorderSide containerBorderSide = BorderSide(
  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
  width: 2,
);

List<String> restoreWords = [
  'Abandon',
  'Ability',
  'Divorce',
  'Leopard',
  'Scale',
  'Lens',
  'Music'
];
```